# Program Installation

Tags: vnc

i just got the Rapberry Pi recently. i was attempting to install a vnc program. so i am trying several ways to get the "ARM" file to install and its not working. is there a default permission,.. because "permission denied" happened when i tried to "./" over an ssh connection. what is the correct way to install this thing?

https://www.realvnc.com/download/vnc/raspberrypi/

i must say that online i came across: "sudo raspi-config" and their picture had a an option "vnc" to turn on or off and my machine there wasn't that option. is that maybe stopping the machine from install this?

Answer (score 2):

The newest version of Raspbian ships with RealVNC installed and only needs to be enabled via raspi-config or the graphical menu. If you are not seeing this option it is clear you have an older version of Raspbian.

To install RealVNC use the following command:

`sudo apt-get install realVNC-VNC-server`

Note the use of **sudo** which will give you temporary root permission to install the software.